# VSCode how to enable xml auto-complete for xml files that using URN xmlns

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code

I am using latest VSCode with `XML Language Support by Red Hat` extension installed, and I am editing a keycloak configuration xml file which looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:12.0">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
        <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-subsystem"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.bean-validation"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.core-management"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.elytron"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config-smallrye"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health-smallrye"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.request-controller"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.security.manager"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
    </extensions>
    ......
```

for such a XML file how can I make auto-complete work ? where to find corresponding schema file ?

Answer (score 1):

$WILDFLY_HOME/docs/schema/wildfly-config_12_0.xsd in your case.

Please note that editing XML is NOT the recommended way to update WildFly configuration. You should use jboss-cli (directly or with an embedded server) or the web-console.